# Is there a set identity_insert on equivalent for SQLite?

Tags: sql-server, sqlite, auto-increment

In TSQL there is

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON;
```

is there a functional equivalent in SQLite?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

SQLite always allows inserting a value into the primary key column; automatically generated values are used only when the inserted value is `NULL` (explicitly or omitted).

For details, see [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

Comment: It says that "On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT keyword is used." Does this mean that it is always AUTOINCREMENT  regardless of defining?

Comment: Read the next paragraph.